# How to list the events fetched from core calendar and display in user designed layout

Tags: java, android

How to create an android project to list the events fetched from core calendar and display in user designed layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query "content://com.android.calendar/events" with a cursor and build up a object you can bind in a list or something.